# How do I do async RPC calls with RabbitMq

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, .net-core

I'm trying to do a RestApi (asp.net core) that calls the backend (C#) through RabbitMq. To handle many requests I will need to call the backend asynchronously.

For me the example code from rabbitmq seem not to be thread-safe because it dequeues messages until the one with the correct correlation id is returned. All others will be ignored. (link: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html )

```
  while(true)
  {
      var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
      if(ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId == corrId)
      {
          return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
      }
  }
```

I'm thinking in the following possibilities:

---

### Possibility 1:

I could use the [SimpleRpcClient](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.8.6/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.8.6-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.SimpleRpcClient.html) and create for each request a own instance. This will cause that for each request a new queue to reply gets created.

### Possibility 2:

Create a own RPC client that creates one reply queue (probably per request type) and returns the right response to the right request depending on the correlation id.

---

What is the best practice to make multiple calls asynchronous? Are there already implementations for the second possibility or do I need to implement this by myself?

Comment: There are implementations of RPC already. For example: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Request-Response

Answer (score 1):

1. Design a job queue, Push job to queue from generator and forget so that job generator remains responsive
2. Have multiple workers equal to number of available CPU threads (*for optimized performance*) to process jobs
3. Each worker to deque job from main queue and put it with results along in new queue.
4. Keep features for

   1. Not to process *too old** jobs.
   2. Terminate **long running** jobs.
   3. Pick **high priority** jobs first.
   4. If permitted design **remote job runner nodes**